# Delete lines from input files excluding patterns listed in another file

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I want to delete lines, matching any of the pattern listed in exclusion file, from input file.

Input file is pretty huge (~500 MB) so I am also looking for efficient solution.

Please note that below example is just a sample and exclusion may contain complex pattern including special characters e.g. `/`

File containing list of exclusions (**exception**)

```
Jun
Jul
Aug
```

Input file (**infile**)

```
Jan 02, 2013
Jul 02, 1988
Feb 02, 1988
Jun 02, 1988
Feb 02, 1988
Aug 02, 1988
Jan 02, 2013
Sep 02, 1988
Mar 02, 1988
Jun 02, 1988
Nov 02, 1988
```

Desired Output (**outfile**)

```
Jan 02, 2013
Feb 02, 1988
Feb 02, 1988
Jan 02, 2013
Sep 02, 1988
Mar 02, 1988
Nov 02, 1988
```

I can use following command, given list of exclusions, and it works fine.

```
egrep -v "Jun|Jul|Aug" infile > outfile
```

My problem is how to get a pipe `|` separated string from exception file and pass it to above grep command? Or is there any other optimum way to achieve this?

I have to implement this as a part of `perl` solution in in which further processing is through hash. But I am open to any linux solution as I can execute those commands from within my perl script.

Your help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Meanwhile people are helping me out with their solutions, I could write following piece of code in `perl` and it also worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $exfread, '<', "exception" or die $!;
chomp ( my @exclusions = <$exfread> );
close $exfread;
my $ex_str = join '|', @exclusions;
# print $ex_str . "\n";

open my $infread, '<', "infile" or die $!;
open my $outfwrite, '>', "outfile" or die $!;

while (<$infread>) {
    next if /${ex_str}/;    
    print $outfwrite $_;
    # do some more processing using hash
}

close $outfwrite;
close $infread;
```

I would love to hear feedback for different approaches with respect to their efficiency. As I mentioned earlier, since my input file is huge and number of files are also significant, next point of worry for me would be run time.

Comment: That is pretty much what I offered as a solution, except that you are unnecessarily compiling the regex for every line of the input file.

Comment: @Borodin saw your ans. Definitely will try out. As I said my next goal will be to pick efficient code with less run time.

Comment: There will be little to choose between different methods. A 500MB file isn't that big, but reading it will take about ten seconds from a hard disk, and writing the same data will take roughly the same. The processing time to check the contents of each line will be insignificant in comparison, so expect a run time of about 20 seconds, regardless of the method you choose.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for detailed explanation. I understand that parsing and storing data in another file won't take much. Please note that I have to created a big hash of hash out of this filtered data. May be I'm doing it inefficiently as it took around 5 min.

Comment: All you have described is filtering `infile` to `outfile` based on `exception`. That should take only a few seconds. I clearly can't comment on anything else you may be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program should suit your purposes. It works by forming a regular expression from the contents of `exception.txt` by joining each line with the alternation operator `|`. Then the regex is compiled with `qr`.

This should prove extremely fast, as only a single regex comparison is performed for each line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $regex = do {
  open my $in,  '<', 'exception.txt';
  my @infile = <$in>;
  chomp @infile;
  local $" = '|';
  qr/@infile/;
};

open my $in,  '<', 'infile.txt';
open my $out, '>', 'outfile.txt';

while (<$in>) {
  print $out $_ unless $_ =~ $regex;
}
```

**output**

```
Jan 02, 2013
Feb 02, 1988
Feb 02, 1988
Jan 02, 2013
Sep 02, 1988
Mar 02, 1988
Nov 02, 1988
```

Comment: I think this solution doesn't worry about special characters, wouldn't be better to `quotemeta()` them? Something like: `$s = join q{|}, map { $_ = q|\\Q| . $_ . q|\\E| } @infile` and then do the `qr`?

Comment: @Birei: Definitely not. Applying `quotemeta` to a regex before it is compiled will escape all the backslashes and have them match as a literal character. Try it.

Comment: @Borodin That works pretty well! I would be grateful if you can comment efficiency of using perl vs grep one liner

Comment: True. I tested it and realised I was mistaken :-) but then how can be solved the escaping of special characters in the strings?

Comment: @jkshah: I can't comment on the efficiency of `grep` in comparison to Perl but, as I commented on your question, unless either is *grossly* inefficient, there will be little to choose between any of them.

Comment: @Birei: You escape them as you would in a literal regex: escape any metacharacters that you want taken literally with a preceding backslash.

Answer (score 2):

for your example, this line works:

```
grep -vf exception infile
```

Comment: That's perfect one liner! Thanks a lot! I should have checked `man grep` :(

Comment: Accepting perl solution as of now but will surely use this next time in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vf patternfile
```

should do the same as a unix command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going outside of Perl, why not just read and filter inside like such?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ifile = 'old.txt';
my $ofile = 'new.txt';

open (my $ifh, '<', $ifile) or die $!;
open (my $ofh, '>', $ofile) or die $!;

while (<$ifh>) {
    print $ofh $_ unless /^Jun|Jul|Aug/;
}

close ($ifh);
close ($ofh);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my main question is to get a list of search pattern from a separate file. I know I can read that file and use `join`. but then search pattern can also contain `/`.

Comment: See @Borodin solution then.